# How do you test a Typescript function in Jasmine?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

This is a straight forward question, yet I can't find an answer. The Jasmine documentation could be improved. It primarily shows examples of spying on mock data and functions, but I want to test the function that I wrote. Otherwise, what am I actually testing? When I've worked with Pipes I've found it much more straight forward as all I have to do is instantiate the pipe with new keyword. And then assert that it returns what I expect. 
e.g.

```
const test = pipe.transform('8726324632');

expect(test).toEqual('872-632-4632');`
```

However, with functions that doesn't seem to work. Take the following code:

```
export function getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement(el) {
    const attributeMap = {};
    Object.keys(el.attributes)
        .forEach(key => {
            attributeMap[el.attributes[key].nodeName] = el.attributes[key].value;
        });

    return attributeMap;
};
```

// My test

```
import { getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement } from './dom';


describe('getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement', () => {
    let mockData;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockData = {
            attributes: {
                a: 'somestring',
                b: 42,
                c: false
            }
        };
    });

    it('should work', () => {

        const myFunc = getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement(mockData);

        expect(myFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Instead of this passing I get the following error in my browser `expected a Spy, but got ({ undefined: undefined }).)`

If I call the function with the `new` keyword I get 
`Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.`

What am I missing here? How can I call my function in my test without having to make one up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasmine errors can be deceptive. Apparently the problem was with the `.toHaveBeenCalled()` method.

When I updated my mock and used `.toEqual()` and `.not.toBeNull()` it passed.

```
describe('getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement', () => {
let mockData;
it('should return null', () => {
    mockData = {
        attributes: {
            a: {
                nodename: 'something',
                value: 'a value'
            }
        }
    };

    expect(getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement(mockData)).not.toBeNull();

});

it('should return attributes', () => {
    mockData = {
        attributes: {
            a: {
                nodename: 'something',
                value: 'a value'
            }
        }
    };
    expect(getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement(mockData)).toEqual({'undefined': 'a value'});

});

it('should return invalid output', () => {
    mockData = {
        attributes: {
            a: {
                nodename: 'something',
                value: 'a value'
            },
            b: {
                name: false,
                value: ''
            }
        }
    };

    expect(getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement(mockData)).toEqual({'undefined': ''});


});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement` is not a spy and this is what Jasmine says. `toHaveBeenCalled` method ca be only applied to Jasmine spy object. `myFunc` is a result of execution, but not a spy.

You have to stub your `getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement` function first, but turns out it is very tricky to create a spy of independent exported function ([see github discussion](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414)).

I would recommend to do not check `toHaveBeenCalled` at all, because it does not make any sense. You usually use `toHaveBeenCalled` on dependencies to test your function in isolation, but not on original function, that you just called. Just test the result against different data sets and that would be 100% correct approach in this case.

Comment: Error: <spyOn> : getKeyValueOfAttributesFromElement is not declared writable or has no setter

Comment: @London804 You're right, check my updated answer, thanks